# SQL : ids containing specific arrays in a specific way

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

An item `table: items` has many taxonomies `table: taxonomies` using a join table `item_taxonomies (item_id, taxonomy_id)`.

A search for items is made using taxonomies groups.

Example:

```
taxo_group_1 = [1, 2, 3]
taxo_group_2 = [4, 5]
```

The sql should find all `items` having `taxonomies` included in both arrays this way:

If I have these elements:

```
item_1 id=1
   taxo_1 id=11
   taxo_2 id=12
   taxo_3 id=13

item_2 id=2
   taxo_3 id=13
   taxo_4 id=14
```

Searching with `[11, 12]` and `[13]` will return `item_1` and not `item_2`, because `item_1` has taxonomies `in [11, 12] AND in [13]`.

`item_2` won't be returned because it has not taxonomies in `[11, 12]`

So far:

```
"taxonomies"."id" IN (11, 12, 13) AND "taxonomies"."id" IN (13)
```

Won't work of course.

Comment: People doing `-1` are all but useful. At least leave a comment. With power comes responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired output using this query :

```
select item from (
    select item, count(distinct taxonomy_id) as count from items  
    join taxonomies on items.item_id = taxonomies.item_id
    where taxonomies.taxonomy_id in (11,12,13)
    group by item
) as T where count = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have unterstood it a bit differently. He/she wants to find all items that have exactly 11, 12 and 13 as taxonomy id.

```
select item from joinedTable 
where taxonomy_id in (11,12,13)
group by item
having count(distinct taxonomy_id) = 3
```

But really I am a bit confused about the request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question you want to get a group who gets all id in entry, in sql it will be :

```
SELECT [...] WHERE taxonomies.id = 11 
   AND taxonomies.id = 12 
   AND taxonomies.id = 13
```